# Show products based on custom field

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce, custom-field

I have a custom field enabled on a product - it is a user field that associates a product with a user.

What would the correct setup be to only display products that pertain to the currentUser - as this would match the custom user field?

Answer (score 1):

Depends on whether the user field is on the product or a variant.

If the custom field is on the product:

```
{% set products = craft.commerce.products.relatedTo({
    sourceElement: currentUser,
    field: 'userFieldName'
}) %}
```

If the custom field is on the variant:

```
{% set variantCriteria = craft.commerce.variants.relatedTo({
    sourceElement: currentUser,
    field: 'userFieldName'
}) %}

{% set products = craft.commerce.products.hasVariant(variantCriteria) %}
```

Comment: The custom field is on the product. I should have added, that I previously attempted your first suggestion, but it didn't return any results.